# Gradient background in android studio

Tags: android

I have a question about android design. I am creating an android application that uses Geofencing and GPS  and i'd loved to add some designs on it especially on backgrounds.Since i'm just a newbie in android programming i just want to ask if do you know some websites or plugins in android studio that auto-generate background gradient in image form or XML form.

Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good site. It's all online and so fast
[Angry tools gradient](http://angrytools.com/gradient/)

Comment: great! appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it from code and set any gradient you want.

```
GradientDrawable gradient = new GradientDrawable(
        GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,    // set orientation
        new int[] {color1, color2});                // any colors you want
gradient.setCornerRadius(radius);
backgroundLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(gradient);
```

If you want random gradients, just generate random colors with

```
Random random = new Random();
float r = random.nextFloat();
float g = random.nextFloat();
float b = random.nextFloat();
Color randomColor = new Color(r, g, b);
```